# Powershell .TrimEnd not returning correct result

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, trim

Running the following

```
$x = "CF21_flddep-op-config"
$x.TrimEnd("-op-config")
```

Results in:

```
CF21_fldde
```

When it should be displaying:

```
CF21_flddep
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.TrimEnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.trimend) does not remove a trailing *string*, it removes a set of trailing *characters*. `p` is in that set, so the last `p` is also removed. (You would get the same result with `.TrimEnd("-cfginop")`, or more explicitly `.TrimEnd('-', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'p')`.) You want something like `$x -replace "-op-config", ""` or, if the string must only be removed when it occurs at the end, `-replace "-op-config$", ""`.

Comment: Thanks! Replace is the better option

Comment: When replacing with nothing you can omit the `,""` part. And as there's nothing to expand I'd use `-replace '-op-config$'`